# xcode device support for 11.3 15E5216a

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to debug on my phone running the latest iOS 11.3 (15E5216a) but the device support folder from Xcode 9.3 Beta 4 only has version 11.3 (15E5201e).  Where can I get the device support files for the latest 11.3 beta?

Trying to run on my iOS device shows an error on xcode saying that the ios version is not supported by this version of XCode.

Comment: Download the non beta version of Xcode 9.3 which was released today along side iOS 11.3

Comment: wow, good timing, yeah downloading the latest release this afternoon did it.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**WITHOUT NEW XCODE**

For lazy guys like me

I don't like to download new version of xcode

And because storage of my macbook is just 120gb, I usually live with "Did Receive Memory Warning"

Here is all iOS Device Support:
(I will update asap)

### iOS 14

1. [14.5](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/14.5(FromXcode_12.5_beta_12E5220o).zip) from Xcode 12.5 beta 12E5220o
2. [14.5](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/14.5(FromXcode_12.5_Release_Candidate_xip).zip) from Xcode 12.5 (Release Candidate)
3. [14.4](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/14.4(FromXcode_12.4(12D4e)).zip) from Xcode 12.4(12D4e)
4. [14.3](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/14.3(FromXcode_12.3_beta_xip).zip) from Xcode 12.3 beta
5. [14.3](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/14.3(FromXcode_12.3_Release_Candidate_xip).zip) from Xcode 12.3 Release_Candidate
6. [14.2](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/14.2(FromXcode_12.3_beta_xip).zip) from Xcode 12.3 beta
7. [14.2](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/14.2(FromXcode_12.2_Release_Candidate_xip).zip) from Xcode 12.2 Release Candidate
8. [14.1](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/14.1(FromXcode12.1(12A7403)).zip) from Xcode 12.1(12A7403)
9. [14.0](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/14.0(FromXcode_12_GM_seed_xip).zip) from Xcode 12 GM seed

### iOS 13

1. [13.0](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/13.0.zip) from xcode 11 beta

### iOS 12

1. [12.3](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/12.3.zip) from xcode 11 beta
2. [12.2 (16E5212e)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/12.2%20(16E5212e).zip)
3. [12.2 (16E5181e)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/12.2%20(16E5181e).zip)
4. [12.2 (16E226)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/12.2%20(16E226).zip)
5. [12.1 (16B92)](https://mega.nz/#!p0FDHCID!A6eMahIRwHKN68StYTWIgg-_nYas9GuKmz5O94FjbFE) This file may not work. Use 16B5059d instead
6. [12.1 (16B91)](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/master/DeviceSupport/12.1%20(16B91).zip)
7. [12.1 (16B5084a)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/12.1%20(16B5084a).zip)
8. [12.1 (16B5068g)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/12.1%20(16B5068g).zip)
9. [12.1 (16B5059d)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/12.1%20(16B5059d).zip) For 16B92, please use this, xcode generates 16B92 folder
10. [12.0 (16A5354b)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/12.0%20(16A5354b).zip)
11. [12.0 (16A5339e)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/12.0%20(16A5339e).zip)
12. [12.0 (16A5327d)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/12.0%20(16A5327d).zip)
13. [12.0 (16A5318d)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/12.0%20(16A5318d).zip)
14. [12.0 (16A5308d)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/12.0%20(16A5308d).zip)
15. [12.0 (16A5288q)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/12.0%20(16A5288q).zip)
16. [12.0 (16A366)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/12.0%20(16A366).zip)

### iOS 11

1. [11.4 (15F79)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/11.4%20(15F79).zip)
2. [11.4 (15F5061c)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/11.4%20(15F5061c).zip)
3. [11.4](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/11.4.zip)
4. [11.4 (15F5037c)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/11.4%20(15F5037c).zip)
5. [11.3](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/11.3.zip)
6. [11.3 (15E5201e)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/11.3%20(15E5201e).zip)
7. [11.3 (15E5167d)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/11.3%20(15E5167d).zip)
8. [11.2](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/11.2.zip)
9. ...

### iOS 10

Need the old files, tell me if you want

### Find DeviceSupport dir

Finder-> Cmd+Shift+G -> Paste **~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport** and enter

Error: **Could not locate device support files** How can fix this error?

.

**------ Update 2018/08/17 -----**

Thanks iGhibli(https://github.com/iGhibli)

**------ Update 2019/10/17 -----**

I got new job, it's about Android. So I no longer use Xcode everyday like before.

**------ Update 2021/08/20 -----**

From xcode 14, DeviceSupport is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`

If there's something new, please comment here, I will update my post asap

Thanks

Comment: I tried using the 11.4 files and I get the error: `An error was encountered while attempting to communicate with this device. (The service is invalid.)`

Comment: I copied the last 11.4 files (new and 15F5037c) and it shows the same message, it ask for the file `11.4 (15F79)` ... you wouldn't happen to have it, would you? (Please!) `This iPad mini 2 (Model A1490) is running iOS 11.4 (15F79), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.`

Comment: @bey23 try restarting Xcode after adding the 11.4 files

Comment: I'd just started raging about the hassle involved in having to update Xcode and potentially macOS again, and then searched hoping for the best. You're my new favourite person on here.

Comment: Update 11.4(15F79), 11.4 (15F5061c)

Comment: could you add 12.1 (16B92)

Comment: Hi,

I need file for iOS 12.3.1(16F203)

Comment: Hi @KAR, please check my update. Sorry for the delay :)

Answer (score 20):

1. [Download 11.3 file](https://github.com/chenhuaizhe/src/blob/master/xcode/11.3%20(15E5189d).zip) for Xcode
2. Find Xcode Application file in your mac, right-click to show contents
3. Go to `Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`, drag the file into it:

[image]

4. reconnect your iPhone in Xcode - Window - Devices and Simulators, and you may need to restart your Xcode and iPhone

Comment: user9414135 you have been granted the rank of Master... This solution works for Xcode 8 also! As long as your share link is still up. I was able to find the .dmg from the iOS 11.3 image, but could not find the signing file. Thanks man!

Comment: I can't find my *Contents* folder. can you please help me? My os is Sierra 10.13.3 and Xcode is 9.4

Answer (score 0):

You can run device with iOS 13.1 in Xcode 10:

1. Download this file [iOS 13.1](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/blob/master/DeviceSupport/13.1.zip)
2. Go to **Xcode/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport**
3. Paste that folder there
4. Restart Xcode.