# iPhone 5s running ios 12.1 not supported in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios12

After updating my iPhone 5 to ios 12.1, I get this error in xcode:

**Could not locate device support files.
This iPhone 5s (Model A1457, A1518, A1528, A1530) is running iOS 12.1 (16B92), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.**

What can I do about this?

Comment: Also, you can try to install support files manually https://stackoverflow.com/a/49808795/4848859

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update Xcode to the latest version on the app store. Had this issue as well.

Comment: @RJB no problem!

Comment: @RJB how to solve, is that possible to without update xcode i wana to run 9.4.1

Comment: @Krishnakushwaha You can only work on iPhone versions that work under xcode 9.4.1. Any iOS versions that came out after 9.4.1 will not work until you update.

Comment: i have the latest version of Xcode 10.0 and i still get this error

Comment: @MikeG 10.1 is the current version which supports iOS 12.1

Comment: ya my bad thanks, Xcode didn't have the update option in its About section and it wasn't showing up in my App Store update page. Just needed to search for it

Answer (score 3):

**Quicker/Smaller Fix**

If you don't want a big `Xcode` update due to limited storage/time then you can manually download the required support files instead of the whole update.

I was on Xcode `9.4` so I downloaded the files from [here](https://github.com/Yatko/iOS-device-support-files) and pasted in `/Applications/Xcode/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`

Answer (score 1):

Give a try with https://github.com/NikKovIos/XcodeDeviceSupportFiles/tree/master/12.1%20(16B91)

Check the readme of the repo to find how to install it.

Answer (score -1):

Download latest supported device support file and add it manually in

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

https://github.com/xushuduo/Xcode-iOS-Developer-Disk-Image/releases

**Enjoy**