# Xcode11.1 crashed when I try to run app on iPhone 11 Pro Max(iOS 13.2)

Tags: ios, xcode

I upgrade my iPhone 11 Pro Max from iOS 13.1.3 to iOS 13.2, and then I try to ran app on my iPhone, but everytime Xcode(11.1) crashed. Here is the log:

```
Process:               Xcode [1358]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               11.1 (15405)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-15405000000000000~13 (11A1027)
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       832925179
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [1358]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-10-30 16:56:32.317 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.1 (19B88)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     4.1 (17P1081)
Anonymous UUID:        XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX


Time Awake Since Boot: 6100 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        7  Dispatch queue: Mutex to protect _hasPerformedWorkerAction

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 11A1027
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Invalid parameter not satisfying: aString != nil
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: 
  0: Calling block provided to DVTSyncPerformBlock() here:

  0   DVTSyncPerformBlock (in DVTFoundation)
  1   -[IDEExecutionRunnableTracker executionWantsHold:withError:] (in IDEFoundation)
  2   -[IDERunOperationWorker _startWithRetrying:] (in IDEFoundation)
  3   __44-[IDERunOperationWorker _startWithRetrying:]_block_invoke_3 (in IDEFoundation)
  4   __48-[DVTDispatchLock_Recursive performLockedBlock:]_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
  5   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
  6   _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete (in libdispatch.dylib)
  7   DVTDispatchBarrierSync (in DVTFoundation)
  8   -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
  9   -[DVTDispatchLock_Recursive performLockedBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
 10   __44-[IDERunOperationWorker _startWithRetrying:]_block_invoke_2 (in IDEFoundation)
 11   __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ (in DVTFoundation)
 12   __DVTDispatchAfter_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
 13   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
```

And I ran same project on another iPhone(iPhone 6s Plus, iOS 13.2), it works well... I don't know why. Is there something wrong with my iPhone 11 Pro Max?

How can I solve this problem...Who can help me?
Thanks.

Comment: What's `aString` or can you pls share some code which you have in `AppDelegate` or in root class?

Comment: Try to clean the derived data folder and also try Products > Clean Build Folder if you have not already tried that

Comment: @Sohil R. Memon THX. I have edited the post. I ran  same project on my another iPhone(iPhone 6s Plus, iOS 13.2), it works fine

Comment: @Bhavesh Bansal I tried, but it doesn't help.

Comment: I don't think iOS 13.2 is supported in 11.1 anyway.  There's a beta of Xcode 11.2.

Comment: @bg2b That's it! Upgrade Xcode to 11.2 solve my problem! Thank you!

Comment: I have the same issue for iPhone 11 / iOS 13.3 / Xcode 11.1. Cleaning DeviceSupport and DerivedData does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to get my iPhone 11 / iOS 13.3 / Xcode 11.1 (`/Applications/Xcode.app`) debug runnning by:

Installing Xcode 11.3.1 @
`/Applications/Xcode11.3.1.app/`

Copying `/Applications/Xcode11.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/13.2` into `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/13.2`

Making a copy of `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/13.2` to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/13.3`

This is a fairly standard practice [xcode device support for 11.3 15E5216a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49564533/xcode-device-support-for-11-3-15e5216a/49808795)
The thing is only using *this particular* `13.2` from Xcode 11.3.1 as `13.3` "imposter" was good enough in my case.